# setting up log4j2 in new web app

Tags: java, log4j2, servlet-3.0

I'm upgrading my web app to include log4j2 and having difficulty configuring. I have my log4j2.xml file located in WEB-INF/classes folder.  I want log4j2 to write to my log file named jed.log in WEB-INF/logs/ folder.  My xml file looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="/WEB-INF/logs/jed.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Log4j2 is definitely logging to the console so I know that part is working, but I can't seem to make it see the log file.  For the `fileName` attribute I've tried setting it to `"/WEB-INF/logs/jed.log"`, `"WEB-INF/logs/jed.log"`, `"../logs/jed.log"`. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Tips: let's write your log with `<File name="MyFile" fileName="jed.log"`. Run the web to make log => go to your web app to find the `jed.log` file => by this way you can check if your config is correct or not and you also know that where is the root dir => from the root dir you can infer the path to the location that you want to save your file.

Comment: Well...I tried it without a path and surprisingly the file wound up being generated in the apache-tomcat-8.5.4/bin directory.  I never would have thought it would wind up there.  So in the end I had to use path: "../webapps/editors/WEB-INF/logs/jed.log"  Thanks for your assistance. It's working fine now.

Comment: Remember to add your comment as an answer and accept it.